# Program works fine with VS2012 but encounters Error when using Tiny C

Tags: c, linked-list, typedef, singly-linked-list

I was wondering what function will I need to copy the data of a `typedef struct` pointer into `typedef struct` array.

```
typedef struct nodebase{
    char company[254];
    int counter;
    int rows;
    int column;
    struct nodebase *next;
}data;
```

I know that I could use `memcpy` for the `char company` but how about for the Integer values?

I want to do something like:

```
int main()
{
data *p;
data item[] = {0};
int counter = 0;

/*Calling for the roster file to scan and store the data into `data *p` using fscanf*/
/*Code for singly linked-list*/
counter++ //This happens everytime the program has scanned 4 variables in the file
item[counter] = p; //This definitely is now working..
```

---

Edited: I am now using `memcpy` and the previous problem has been solved.

(Thank you for your answers!)

Now, I am encountering a new problem and that is in my singly linked-list.

Apparently, there are 12 "counter" in the roster file (That means, there are 48 variables in the roster file to read and store the data).

```
//Code for Singly Linked-list
int main()
{
data *p;
data *head;
data *tail;
data item[] = {0};
FILE *f;
int counter = 0;

head = NULL;
tail = NULL;

while(!feoe(f)
{
    p = malloc(sizeof(data));
/*Opens the roster file and Read & Store the data in the file to the respective variables inthe `typedef struct`.*/
    if(head ==NULL)
    {
        head = p;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = p;
    }
    tail = p;

    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        do{
           printf(":||%s||: Name",p->name); //Just to check if the linked list is working
           memcpy(&item[counter], p, sizeof(data*));
           counter++;
           p = p->next;
           p = NULL;
        }while(p!=NULL);
    }free(p);
}
}
```

Problem: When printing each names of the 12 "sets" from the roster file, the program prints the first 10 sets correctly then it suddenly stops working. (Using Tiny C on Windows)

And the bizzare thing is, when I compile this file with VS2012, it works fine.

Comment: This code makes no sense.  You have an array with no size? You have a pointer that points to no memory and you're trying to write to an array out of its bounds.  Does it even compile??

Comment: @TonyTheLion Apparently, It can be compiled using VS2012. Can you tell me if there is any way to use an array whose size will be yet to be assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy the content pointed by a `struct nodebase *` (aka `data *`) into a `struct nodebase []` (`data []`), you could indeed use a `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(&item[counter], p, sizeof(struct nodebase));
```

As stated in `memcpy` documentation:

> The underlying type of the objects pointed by both the source and destination pointers are irrelevant for this function; The result is a binary copy of the data.

So it does not matter if it is integers or anything else.

However, you will need a big enough array. so be sure to instantiate your `item` array with a big enough size.

Comment: My `counter` will add 1 everytime when 5 variables has been read and stored from the file. Do I need to use `realloc`?

Comment: It is better if you have a big enough array from the beggining, since `realloc` will take lots of ressources. If you have no idea of the array size, it might be better to use a chained list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
memcpy(&item[counter], p, sizeof(data));
```

your above statement is invalid

```
item[counter] = p;
```

Look at the types